# Adding Subpaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $F$ is a field, $V$ is a vector space over F, and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ . Assume $a \in F$. Prove that $U + (aU) = U$.

Here is my approach:

1). Check $U+aU \subseteq U$ ?Suppose $u\in U+aU$ therefore $u= u_1+a u_2$ ,where $u_1,a u_2 ∈U$. Hence $U+aU \subseteq U$.

2). Check $U \subseteq U+aU$? Suppose $u\in U$, therefore $u=u+0$ such that $u \in U$ and $0\in aU$.Then $u \in U+aU$ since $a∙0=0 \in aU$. Hence, $U \subseteq U+aU$.

How do prove this on in more rigorous way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have done it rigorously enough. I don't see a way to improve on an essential way.

Comment: Do you think so? But I still feel like the way I prove for the other direction is not very good. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: For proving that $U\subseteq U+aU$ it is evidently enough to show that $0\in aU$ wich follows immediately from $0\in U$ (hence $0=a.0\in aU$). Is that "the other direction"?

Comment: Yes! that was what I meant by "the other direction". Thanks!